# C++ Non-virtual function call in a virtual call

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, this, virtual

Why is the output of this program "CLASS A"? Isn't *this* determined to be of type B? Doesn't it mean that this->g() should call the B class's version of g?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
private:
    void g() {
        cout << "CLASS A" << endl;
    }
public:
    virtual void f() {
        g();
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void g() {
        cout << "CLASS B" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A* a = new B();
    a->f();
}
```

Comment: You make the wrong function `virtual`. It's the `g` function that needs to be `virtual`, not `f`.

Comment: Only `f()` is virtual, not `g()` - `g()` would be early bound, not late-bound. It doesn't matter if called from a virtual function.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't this determined to be of type B?

No. `B` may be the dynamic type, but the static type of `*this` is `A` within all its member functions.

The member function `g` is not virtual, so therefore a call to it uses static binding. In static binding, the dynamic type of the object is irrelevant - only the static type matters. A call to the non-virutal `g` within a member function of `A` should be a call to `A::g`.